# C++ Iterators, interfaces and pointers

Tags: c++, interface, vector, iterator

I'm trying to use c++ iterators with interfaces, but does not manage to make it working.

I'm a bit lost with what type to choose for the vector contents. Is this need to be a pointer ? do I have to make a "new Implementation()"? In brief, it is unclear to me, and I can't manage to find useful examples about that.

Here are the interfaces and implementations (the .h file).

```
class Interface{
public:
virtual int method() = 0;
};

class Implementation1 : public Interface{
    public:
    int method(); 
};

class Implementation2 : public Interface{
    public:
    int method();
};
```

The .cpp file:

```
#include "content.h"

int Implementation1::method(){
    return 1;
}

int Implementation2::method(){
    return 2;
}
```

And my main function:

```
#include "content.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    // create the vector and put elements in it
    vector<Interface*> elements;
    elements.push_back(new Implementation1());
    elements.push_back(new Implementation1());
    elements.push_back(new Implementation2());

    // now iterate on them

    vector<Interface*>::iterator iterator;
    for(iterator = elements.begin(); iterator != elements.end(); ++iterator ){
        *iterator->method();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

the compilator is outputting:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   main.cpp:19: error: request for member
>   ‘method’ in ‘*
>   iterator.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-> with _Iterator = Interface**, _Container = std::vector >’,
>   which is of non-class type
>   ‘Interface*’

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: it is a compilation failure, yes. I've added the output of g++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `*iterator->method();` to `(*iterator)->method();`

The former dereferences the return of iterator->method().  Interface* doesn't have a method(), it doesn't have anything.

You want to dereference the iterator to get to your pointer, and then dereference IT.

You've basically got the same thing as Iterator** so act accordingly.

Comment: To elaborate: `->` takes precedence over `*`, the same way as `*` in `2 * 2 + 2` has a higher precedence than `+`.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Noah about the compile error with iterator, that's a good explanation. As for your former question:

> I'm a bit lost with what type to choose for the vector contents. Is this need to be a pointer ? do I have to make a "new Implementation()"?

Yes, this has to be a pointer. The reason is simple: **the vector of type T stores (and owns) only elements of type T**, not subtypes - and there are good reasons for that (what if the subclass had a different size?).

Therefore you have to store the objects somewhere and keep the pointers in the vector. In fact, storing them on the free store via `operator new` is the easiest option.

If you want your life a bit easier, you can use `boost::ptr_vector` for your purposes.

Comment: You can also use smart pointers.  For instance, depending on your needs, you might use `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`.  Just don't use auto_ptr or scoped_ptr; they might seem to work but aren't legal vector content.

Comment: Agreed (but that's still c++0x, so `ptr_vector` is my no.1 recommendation ATM).

Answer (score 0):

try `(*iterator)->method();`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently invalid about what you've done, but creating a vector of raw pointers is typically a bad idea, you should use an ownership enforcing pointer (a "smart" pointer) like shared_ptr. And you also don't need to de-reference the iterator, it should just offer ->method() directly. However, I don't see anything directly uncompilable with this code, except possibly your `*iterator->method()`, cause last time I checked de-reference has a really low precedence and you may be doing `*(iterator->method())` which is uncompilable.

Comment: While the remark about having a vector of raw pointers being sub-optimal in terms of error-proneness (compared to i.e. a vector of smart pointers) is correct, suggesting a reference-counted smart pointer where it's not needed is uncool (and sub-optimal in terms of efficiency, which is still bad). There are better solutions: the `boost::ptr_vector` or a plain vector of smart pointers like `unique_ptr` (c++0x).